# Проблемы с переключением языка

Tags: codeblocks

Когда меняю язык (shift+alt) и хочу продолжить писать, первая нажатая клавиша после смены языка не печатается, а вместо этого комп издает "предупредительный звук". При чем такая фигня только в codeblocks, в браузере язык переключается нормально.

Comment: ?? не встречал такого поведения в c::b, это забавно :) поотключайте плагины, по очереди, и проверьте пользовательские команды по горячим клавишам, может там чего то заведено на shift+alt.

Comment: @NewView Я решил проблему, но она решилась очень странно. Я просто сменил клавиши для смены языка( с shift+alt  на shift+ctrl) и теперь  все работает...

Comment: Я в принципе это и имел в виду, что в c::b где то заведено хот-кей с этой комбинацией клавиш.